swiper-container not registering events
i'm creating an app in ionic/angular and i'm trying to move between cards by using the swiper and it is working however the swiper-container is not registering events.
I'm using this events so that i know the current card.
I'm using ionic version 5.4.16
// tab2.page.html
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <swiper-container #swiper (afterinit)="swiperReady()" (slidechange)="onSlideChange($event)">
    <swiper-slide *ngFor="let character of characters">
      <ion-card>
        <img [src]="character.image" class="character-image">
        <ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-title>{{character.name}}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>{{character.description}}</ion-card-content>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name='trophy' item-start style="color:#d03e84"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Trophies</ion-label>
          <ion-badge item-end>{{character.fighting_style}}</ion-badge>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name='logo-twitter' item-start style="color:#55acee"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Followers</ion-label>
          <ion-badge item-end>{{character.weapon}}</ion-badge>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-card>
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Tab 2</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-button expand="block" (click)="openMenu1()">
    Character Actions
  </ion-button>
</ion-content>

// tab2.page.ts
import Swiper from 'swiper';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('swiper') swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined;
  swiper?: Swiper;
  selected_index = 0;
  characters = CHARACTERS;

  constructor(
    private actionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
    private modalController: ModalController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Assuming you have fetched or assigned characters data
  }

  async openMenu1() {
    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
      header: 'Character',
      mode: 'ios',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Play Video',
        icon: 'arrow-dropright-circle',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Play clicked');
          this.presentModal();
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Follow',
        icon: 'logo-twitter',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Favorite clicked');
        }
      }, {
        text: 'Cancel',
        icon: 'close',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: () => {
          console.log('Cancel clicked');
          console.log('selected_index: ', this.selected_index)
        }
      }]
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }

  async presentModal() {
    let url = this.characters[this.selected_index].url;
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModalpagePage,
      componentProps: { value: url }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }

  swiperReady() {
    this.swiper = this.swiperRef?.nativeElement.swiper;
  }

  onSlideChange(e: any) {
    console.log('is entering on onSlideChange');
    //this.selected_index = e.target.swiper.activeIndex
    this.selected_index =this.swiperRef?.nativeElement.swiper.activeIndex;
    console.log('selected_index: ', this.selected_index);
  }

}


// tab2.module.ts
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ExploreContainerComponentModule,
    Tab2PageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [Tab2Page],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class Tab2PageModule {}

// app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

register();

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {}
}

i tried to use ionic-slides but it's not working the tab2 is in dropdown mode i've tried to debug it but i i'm a noob in ionic and angular in general

Do you get anything in those methods if you put console.log inside a setTimeout(), with timer of 0?

unfortunately I'm getting nothing
